# How should a battery be stored?

Tags: laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery Life Practice](https://superuser.com/questions/13024/battery-life-practice)
>   [What is it that kills laptop batteries?](https://superuser.com/questions/77457/what-is-it-that-kills-laptop-batteries)
>   [Storing a laptop for a month](https://superuser.com/questions/314951/storing-a-laptop-for-a-month)

I want to remove and store my laptop battery so that it doesn't get spoilt over time. So how should i store it? And how should i cover the battery slot in the laptop? One more thing, after how much time should i put the battery in again?

Comment: Related: [Is it safe to store a battery in the freezer?](http://superuser.com/questions/377650/is-it-safe-to-store-a-battery-in-the-freezer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/197864, http://superuser.com/questions/314951, http://superuser.com/questions/77457, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Store Li-Ion batteries between 20°C and 25°C (68°F and 77°F) with 30% to 50% charge.
>
> Do not disassemble, crush, or puncture a battery; do not short the external contacts on a battery; and, do not dispose of a battery in fire or water.
>
> Do not leave batteries exposed to high temperatures for extended periods. Prolonged exposure to heat (for example, inside a hot car) accelerates the deterioration of Li-Ion cells.
>
> Remove the battery if the notebook will be stored (turned off and not plugged into AC power) for more than 2 weeks.
>
> Remove the battery from the notebook if the notebook will be plugged into AC power continuously (via a wall adapter or docking station) for more than 2 weeks.

[Source of Information](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01297640&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en#N107)

Comment: So in what conditions should i store it in? And how should u seal off the battery slot in the laptop?

Comment: Conditions are in my answer, no need to seal the battery bay, never seen anyone do that.